# Getting Error 'File is being used' when trying to delete file c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have windows service which periodically fetches data from table and creates excel file and mails it to users.After mail sending I need to delete that file. Have used following code:

```
public void LABInstrumentExcelGeneration(string filePath) {
    try {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString(filePath);

        List < LABInstruments > listLABInstrument = null;
        listLABInstrument = new List < LABInstruments > ();
        listLABInstrument = LABInstrumentBL.GetLABInstrumentList();
        if (listLABInstrument.Count > 0) {
            using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [table2] (SrNo string,CalibrationDoneOn Date);";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                foreach(LABInstruments tc1 in listLABInstrument) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table2](SrNo,CalibrationDoneOn) VALUES('" + tc1.SrNo + "','" + tc1.CalibrationDoneOn + "');";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
 }

 SendMail(filePath, role);

 if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
    File.Delete(filePath);
    eLog.WriteEntry("file deleted");
 }
```

But it gives error File is being used by another process. 
Ho can I delete file? Moreover, i've used OLEDB for file creation. Is there any other best practise for file creation? Have tried ExcelLibrary, but files created in it does not work in all versions of office so have dropped it.

Comment: You don't need to use `conn.Close()` and `conn.Dispose();` as the object will get disposed automatically because of the `using` block. Also use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection

Comment: When your service is creating the files, are you making sure to File.Close() after creation?

Comment: I've not explicitly opened the file, So file.Close() is not needed.

Comment: Can you please provide the code how you generate the file?

Comment: Have already specified in code above. Please check

Comment: Please show where you are calling `SendMail()`. I guess you are calling it at the wrong time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected virtual bool IsLocked(FileInfo fileName)
{
   FileStream fStream = null;
   try
   {
        fStream = fileName.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
   }
   catch (IOException)
   {
        return true;
   }
   finally
   {
        if (fStream != null)
        {
             fStream.Close();
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```

And then:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    FileInfo myfile = new FileInfo(filePath);
    if(IsLocked(myfile))
    {
        File.Create(filePath).Close();
        File.Delete(filePath);
        eLog.WriteEntry("file deleted");
    }
    else
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
        eLog.WriteEntry("file deleted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that sendmail returns before it has finished using the file.

Instead of sendmail() I used this function which frees up the file for deletion:

```
    public static void send(string subject, string body, string from, string to, List<string> attachments = null)
    {
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(from), new MailAddress(to)))
        {
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in attachments)
                {                        
                    if (s != null)
                    {
                        /* this code fixes the error where the attached file is 
                         * prepended with the path of the file */
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(s, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                        ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
                        disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(s);
                        disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(s);
                        disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(s);
                        disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
                        disposition.Size = new FileInfo(s).Length;
                        disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
                        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                }
            }
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }
    }
```